# What font does google translate use?

Tags: google-translate

What font does google translate use and can you use it in an ebook for kindle?

[Google translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7lQ5.png)

Comment: This is in no way a programming-related question, which makes it off-topic here. You can easily inspect the source yourself to see which font is used. The legal question about whether you can use it or not is also off-topic here. You may want to review the [help] guidelines to refresh your understanding of what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Roboto, and yes, you can use it (it's available under [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)).

You can find it on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) as well as the license information.

### Finding fonts for yourself

On webpages, it's quite easy to find which font is in use. Just right-click the element you want to know, Inspect Element, and check the cascading stylesheet. You'll probably see a `font-family` property and that's it.